# Change TextColor of XamarinForms Entry when controls is focused

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I have a project with a UWP Application and the mobile version of that written in Xamarin Forms. Now I want to reuse as much code as possible and in that sense replace some of the simpler UWP views with embedded Xamarin Forms controls.

For startes I testing with a view with only two Entries and two labels. In the light theme everything is fine so far. But in the dark theme the text of the entry is no visible when I enter something due to the fact that the primary text color is white.

[image]
[image]

I have a Style defined for the entry to set the text color:

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultEntryStyle" TargetType="Entry">
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{x:Static presentation:StyleHelper.PrimaryFontColor}" />
</Style>
```

But so far I haven't found any for a state when the entry is focused. Is that possible to accomplish with xamarin forms?

Comment: OK, I've deleted the answer as I've got your question wrong, I thought it relates on why the background is white. You should post your answer now so that people know that you don't need help anymore.

Comment: The entry view doesn't have a property to directly change the focus color. Instead, you need to create a custom renderer to change the text color for each platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the the custom style was the problem. With setting the TextColor to a fix value it overrode the behaviour on windows.
As @sha suggested in the comments, if you have to have another TextColor you have to write a Custom renderer.